# angularjs/CSS: is there a way to set a scroll top position from within inline style?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

My controller stores the scrollTop value of a vertical menu which I want to setup each time I get back to the page to make the scrolling persistent.

Is there a way to do that?

My code is as follows:

```
<nav id="menu" class="menu" ng-style="{'scrollTop': scrollTop+'px'}">
    <table>
      <!-- etc. -->
    </table>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with. As it sounds like no scrollTop CSS property exist, I have called javacrypt to the rescue.

The controller can simply call the scrollTop = scroll on the related element, say in my case:

```
$('#menu')[0].scrollTop = $scope.scroll;
```

The view is now as follows: